# STM32F4329II Input capture Interrupt ignored

Tags: input, capture

STM32F4329II Input capture Interrupt is ignored while trying to use the input capture

```
static void TIM_Config(void)

{

       RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOH, ENABLE);

       GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

       GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_11;

       GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;

       GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;

       GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;

       GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL; //GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;

       GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOH, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_TIM5);   

       GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStructure);

       /* TIM5 clock enable */

       RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM5, ENABLE);

       TIM_ICInitTypeDef  TIM_InputCaptureInitStructure;

       TIM_InputCaptureInitStructure.TIM_Channel = TIM_Channel_2;

       TIM_InputCaptureInitStructure.TIM_ICPolarity = TIM_ICPolarity_Falling;

       TIM_InputCaptureInitStructure.TIM_ICSelection = TIM_ICSelection_DirectTI;

       TIM_InputCaptureInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;

       TIM_InputCaptureInitStructure.TIM_ICFilter = 0x0;

       TIM_ICInit(TIM5, &TIM_InputCaptureInitStructure);

       TIM_ClearFlag(TIM5, TIM_FLAG_CC2 );

       NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

       NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM5_IRQn ;

       NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;

       NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;

       NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;          // 

       NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

       TIM_PWMIConfig(TIM2, &TIM_ICInitStructure);

         //Enable CC2 interrupt
       TIM_ITConfig(TIM5,TIM_IT_CC2,ENABLE);
      //EnableTIM5
       TIM_Cmd(TIM5,ENABLE);

}
```

And the following  IRQ

```
    extern "C" void TIM5_IRQHandler(void)
    {
     if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM5, TIM_IT_CC2) == SET)
     {
         TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM5, TIM_IT_CC2);

         rpm4 = TIM_GetCapture2(TIM5);
         static char xx[12];
         sprintf( xx, " %l", rpm4 );
         GUI_DispStringAt(xx,100,150);
     }

     TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM5, TIM_IT_CC2 );
}
```

I put some breakpoints inside the Interrupt routine but nothing happens...
My external signal is a 5V signal ( this micro is 5V tolerant... ) with negative pulses...

Comment: Well, how far do the pulses get? That is can see whether see the pin is toggling through, the timer channel counting, and capture value latched, interrupt flag raised, and so on via manual polling. Conversely you might verify that the interrupt triggers when manually asserted. Lastly, the type of high-level UI action invoked here looks rather dubious from within an interrupt handler. Please consider asserting a flag or otherwise doing the bare minimum to forward the event to the rest of the system.

Comment: Better explaining, my pulses are negative pulses starting from 5V (the assumption is that the ports are 5V tolerant ), and a period of 200 ms. I obviously checked it through an oscilloscope. Now I  just checked another similar timer, the TIM2, but just updating, with no input capture function. Neither the related TIM2_IRQHandler fires !